# What's the correct name for a Python Extension-thingy?

Tags: python, naming-conventions, python-c-api

Is it:

- Extension class
- Extension type
- Extension object

?

Could somebody disambiguate?

I'm asking because I have the following object structure in my C++ code, and I'm trying to figure out whether I should revise the names before I release my code:

```
class ExtObjBase_noTemplate : public PyObject


template< typename FinalClass >
class ExtObjBase : public FuncMapper<FinalClass> , public ExtObjBase_noTemplate


// - - - - - - - 

template<typename FinalClass>
class ExtObj_old : public ExtObjBase<FinalClass>

template<typename FinalClass>
class ExtObj_new : public ExtObjBase<FinalClass>


//= = = = = = = = = = = 
//CONSUMER does:

class new_style_class: public ExtObj_new< new_style_class >

class old_style_class: public ExtObj_old< old_style_class >
```

Answer (score 1):

**Extension class**, **Extension type**:

These are synonyms, if we ignore classic (old-style) classes.  They refer to classes or types created in extension modules.

Sometimes, we do care about classic classes.  New-style classes are types.  Classic classes are not types.  I don't recommend working with classic classes in new code.  They have been removed in Python 3.

**Extension object**

I've not heard this term before, but I would assume it refers to an instance of an extension class/type.